# Why do two indices need to increment/decrement while checking two chars if that is already done before?

Tags: java

I was recently practicing algorithms on leetcode and came upon a solution to a palindrome question.

My question is why does the last `else if` condition need to post-increment and post-decrement `i` and `j` to index a letter, if that is already happening in the two conditions above?

I noticed that it causes an infinite loop without it. But since the instructions are in a for loop and if the condition evaluated as false `(c[i++]==c[j--])` then nothing would happen. Then `i` would increment at the start of the for-loop again, thus an infinite loop should be impossible. That is what I understand, so far.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i=0, j=c.length-1; i<j;) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c[i])) i++;
            else if (!Character.isLetter(c[j])) j--;
            else if (Character.isLetter(c[i++])!=Character.isLetter(c[j--])) { // c[i++], c[j--] ???
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that clause doesn't evaluate to true, you don't `return`, and you don't want to recheck the same values the next time through the loop.

Comment: Why do you even care about a solution that doesn't work? That code does not check for palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, that for loop isn't actually an 'increment a number from X to Y' construct. It can do more than that. It's *usually* used to increment a number from X to Y:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... runs 10 times, i will be 0-9 }
```

It is **not** used like that here. The above is syntax sugar for:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
   ...
   i++;
}
```

In other words, the first bit (`int i = 0`) is run once only. Then the second bit is used to check if we should loop (`i < 10`) and finally the third bit is executed between loops, right before the condition is checked to see if the loop should go again, or end.

The crucial bit is that the for loop used here has **nothing** for the third bit. No code is executed between loops. Thus, **The loop itself will not be incremening `i` and `j` at all**.

The block itself has to do that, and the third line within that block does the job.

The first 2 lines inside the loop (`!if (Character.isLetter(c[i])`) are just checking for non-letters. It's trying to say that e.g. "12a man a canal panama123143" counts as a palindrome. They don't increment except to skip non-letters.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why does the last `else if` condition need to post-increment and post-decrement `i` and `j` to index a letter, if that is already happening in the two conditions above?

Because if you execute the `else if` test, this *didn’t happen above*, because the other two conditions were `false`, and the bodies of the `if` statements were therefore not executed.

The only situation in which the `else if` test is executed at all is when neither of the previous conditions yielded `true`. So neither `i++` nor `j--` was executed, so the next iteration of the loop will see the exact same `i` and `j` values, unless you handle them in the last `else if` test, even if that also yields `false` and doesn’t execute its body.

As noted in the comments, be aware that your code does *not* test for palindromic strings. In fact, *it will **never** return `false`*, because the last `else if` will never be `true`: you’re not comparing the characters at indices `i` and `j`, you are only comparing whether they’re both (non-)characters. You need to change your last condition to

```
…
else if (c[i++] != c[j--]) return false;
```